# P-value correction: Correlating numeric and categorical variables

Tags: r, statistical-significance, p-value, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

I have a data frame with the first set of columns as continuous variables and another set of columns as categorical variables. The dataset dimension is approximate 2000 observations and 2500 variables. About 250 of the variables are categorical and the rest are continuous.

1. Run a comparison of every continuous variable with every categorical variable. This is presumably done using ANOVA (`aov` in R).
2. Run a comparison of every pair of categorical variables with each other. I guess I'll use a t-test for this.

Do I need to apply a p-value correction using Benjamini-Hochberg or Bonferroni?

Comment: Although this question mentions R, the actual question is about the appropriate correction for the p-values. This is on topic here.

Comment: So you intend to do something like $250\times2500=625000$ tests. Under null, $0.05\times625000=31250$ of them will give significant results at unadjusted $\alpha=0.05$. Is that acceptable for your study?

Comment: For 2, comparing two categorical variables, you don't want to use t-test, but something like a chi-square test of association or G-test of association.  For 1, instead of anova, you might consider a test with fewer assumptions about the data, like kruskal-wallis....  In both cases, you don't want to ignore effect sizes.  With 2000 observations, you are likely to find significant correlations with a small effect size.  Effect sizes you might look at: anova: eta-squared.  kruskal-wallis: epsilon-squared, Freeman's theta.  chi-square, etc:  Cramer's V.